# SQL Agent Export Job is failing with Access is Denied error

Tags: sql-server-2014, export-to-excel, sql-agent-job

I have created an export task to export a view into an excel file onto a folder location. The task runs fine and exports to excel in the correct place. I ahve now saved this task in SSIS.

I am now trying to create a SQL agent scheduled job to run the task daily. I have SQLServerAgent and MSSQLServer access to the folder location however it keeps failing with the error:

```
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x3FF5419F86864B47A653A928777E56DE (reason: Access is denied).  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
```

I have looked this up online and there were suggestions to try ticking the use 32bit runtime checkbox which i have also tried and still keep getting the same error.

Does anyone know what i can do to get the SQL agent job to run successfully?

Comment: Check if the login has all the required Permissions on folder.

Comment: I have checked and the logins have read and write privilages to the folder

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using the proxy account to run that job ?

Comment: I am using a proxy account to run the job.

Comment: Can you try running the job with SysAdmin access to that login?

Comment: it does have access to SysAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause. The reason was I gave SQLServerAGent read/write access to the folder but it needed modify permission. Once i gave it modify it worked fine